# Getting wrong results when using switched-capacitor filter. (PSpice simulation)

Tags: active-filter

Okay the idea is to use the following band-pass active filter:

[image]

To this filter I want to add a switched-capacitor filter to replace the resistors with capacitors and switches. I'm using the formulas \$f_{c1}=\frac{1}{2\pi R_1C_1}\$ and  \$f_{c2}=\frac{1}{2\pi R_2C_2}\$ with \$f_{c1}=2kHz\$. Using those formulas with \$R1=R2=2k\$ we get \$C_1=39.78n\$ and \$C_2=19.89n\$. Finally, we just need to replace the resistors. For that I want to use a clock with \$T_s=1MHz\$ and to calculate the needed capacitors I'm using \$C=\frac{1}{T_sR}\$. Then, the capacitors have the same value (because of the same resistors) and are qual to 0.5nF. The schematic is:
[image]

All seems fine. However I find the following problems:

1. The bandwidth isn't the desired (it should be 2k, but I get about 4k).
2. The working of the circuits seems independant of the clock pulse. I tried changing it from 1Ghz to 1Hz and the response in frequency is the same. That is strange because clearly something should change if I change the clock.

[image]

So, what is going on here? What could be wrong? Am I ignoring something?

Answer (score 1):

How did you simulate the frequency response for the S/C circuit? Note that you must not apply the ac analysis in the frequency domain. This analysis is allowed only for linear - and time continuous - systems. That is the reason for not observing any influence of the clock frequency.

For finding/simulating the transfer function in the frequency domain you must replace all S/C blocks with time-continuous equivalent blocks.

For this purpose there exist two basic techniques as described in the relevant literature.

Comment: The OP could use a simulator like SIMPLIS that can do frequency response on a transient model.  But for PSPICE you need the averaged models.

Comment: @JohnD Or a frequency sweep in `.TRAN` (costly, but with real results).